# How can i use a variable in the place of a column name in C#.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, variables

I have a database with a table.  The first column is `BusID` and the rest of the columns are the seats positions, in the cells.  1 stands for available seat and 0 if the seat cannot be taken (not available )

The user entered the seat position and I put it into a variable, then I did

```
var bus = db.Seats.Find(BusID);
bus.seatPostion = 0;
db.savechanges();
```

This gives me an error for `using a variable in the place of the column`, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: what is `db` and what is (BusID);

Comment: and what is the actual text of the error,and what line does the error occur on

Comment: i got a table in a database where BusID is the first column name, and db is.. i dont what u people call it but its defined like "XXEntities db = new XXEntities();" at the first of the controller, the errors says "models.seats does not contain a definition for 'SeatPostion' and no extension method 'SeatPostion' accepting a first argument of type 'models.seats' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" on line "bus.seatPostion=0

Comment: Show the declaration of the `BusID` variable.

Comment: BusID is the name of the first column in the table, "public long BusID { get; set; }"

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that your table looks something like this: BusId, Seat1, Seat2, Seat3, ...? Or does it look like BusId, SeatId, IsAvailable with a row for each bus and seat combination (a bus with 50 seats has 50 rows in this table, a bus with 30 seats only 30)?

Comment: yes it was (busid,seat1,seat2,seat3..) now i changed it to have only 3 columns (busID, SeatID, SeatState) now every bus with 50 seats got 50 rows, still cant figure out how to select a row depending on 2 columns values (BusID and SeatID) so i can change the seatState..

Answer (score 0):

you have to work with the model of the bus item.Lets say you have context model for your bus:

```
public class Bus
{
    public long BusID { get; set; }
    public long SeatPosition { get; set; }
}

var busId = your user input;
Bus bus = db.Seats.Find(busId);
if(bus != null)
{
   bus.SeatPosition = 0;
}
db.saveChanges();
```